# Reputation on editing same answer twice?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I got 2 reputation twice, for editing the same answer twice. Is this a feature or a bug?

[image: +4 for editing the same post]

Comment: Call it a feature and enjoy the reputation ...

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature.

The earned reputation is calculated from the number of edits, even if they come from the same post. This is intended behavior.